# Unable to resolve module syntaxpos.db

Tags: reactjs, react-native, sqlite, expo

Am trying to create a point of sale system that uses an Sqlite database on the phone using package expo-sqlite when i do it with const db = SQLite.openDatabase('dbName') it works just fine but when i try to import  an external database, it reurns this error:
1:Error: Unable to resolve module `./debugger-ui/debuggerWorker.aca173c4` from ``:
2:ReferenceError: Component is not defined and unable to resolve module
**HERE IS THE GITHUB REPO https://github.com/16isaac89/point-of-sale**

this is the code where i import from and use it

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  Text,
  StatusBar,
  ImageBackground,
  Image,
  TextInput,
  Dimensions,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from 'react-native';




import bgImage from '../assets/images/bgImage.jpg'
import logoLogin from '../assets/images/logos.png'
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons'
import Icons from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome'
import * as actions from '../Redux/Actions';
import { connect } from "react-redux";
 import * as FileSystem from 'expo-file-system'; 
 import {Asset} from "expo-asset";
const { width: WIDTH } = Dimensions.get('window')
 import * as SQLite from 'expo-sqlite'





class Login extends Component {
  getCurrentDate=()=>{
    var date = new Date(); /* creating object of Date class */
    var hour = date.getHours();
    var min = date.getMinutes();
    var sec = date.getSeconds();
    var midday = "AM";
    midday = (hour >= 12) ? "PM" : "AM"; /* assigning AM/PM */
    hour = (hour == 0) ? 12 : ((hour > 12) ? (hour - 12): hour); /* assigning hour in 12-hour format */
    hour = this.updateTime(hour);
    min = this.updateTime(min);
    sec = this.updateTime(sec);
    return  hour + " : " + min + " : " + sec + " " + midday; /* adding time to the div */
      var t = setTimeout(currentTime, 1000)
}
updateTime=(k)=> { /* appending 0 before time elements if less than 10 */
  if (k < 10) {
    return "0" + k
  }
  else {
    return k;
  }
}







  openDatabaseIShipWithApp =async()=> {
    const internalDbName = "syntaxpos.db"; // Call whatever you want
     const sqlDir = FileSystem.documentDirectory + "SQLite/";
     if (!(await FileSystem.getInfoAsync(sqlDir + internalDbName)).exists) {
        await FileSystem.makeDirectoryAsync(sqlDir, {intermediates: true});
         const asset = Asset.fromModule(require("./assets/db/"));
         await FileSystem.downloadAsync(asset.uri, sqlDir + internalDbName);
     }
    return SQLite.openDatabase(internalDbName);
   }




 
async componentDidMount(){
  // this.openDatabaseIShipWithApp()
 console.log(this.props.dataUser)
  if(this.props.loggedin === true){
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Home');
  }
 
 
}


onAuthComplete=(props)=>{
  if(this.props.loggedin = true){
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Main');
  }
}
loginPin = () =>{
  let username = this.props.username
   let password = this.props.lpin;
   //console.log(username, password)
   this.props.getUser({username,password})
}

onPinChange(text){
  this.props.pinChanged(text);
 }
 onusernameChange(text){
  this.props.usernameChanged(text);
 }
   


 render(){
  return (
      <ImageBackground source={bgImage} style={styles.backgroundContainer}>
        <View style={styles.logoContainer}>
          <Image source={logoLogin} style={styles.logoLogin} />
          <Text style={styles.logoText}>Business Management Made Easier</Text>
          <Text style={styles.textLogin}>LOGIN</Text>
        </View>

  
        <View>
          <Icons name={'user'} size={28} color={'black'}
            style={styles.inputIcon}/>
          <TextInput
           onChangeText={this.onusernameChange.bind(this)}
           value = {this.props.username}
            style={styles.inputUsername}
            placeholder={'USER NAME'}
            placeholderTextColor={'black'}
            underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
    
          />
        </View>
        <View>
          <Icon name={'ios-lock'} size={28} color={'black'}
            style={styles.inputIcon}/>
          <TextInput
           onChangeText={this.onPinChange.bind(this)}
           value = {this.props.lpin}
            style={styles.inputUsername}
            placeholder={'PIN'}
            placeholderTextColor={'black'}
            underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
            keyboardType = 'numeric'
          />
        </View>

  
        <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={.7} style={styles.btnLogin} onPress={()=> this.loginPin()}>
          <Text style={styles.textsubmit} > LOGIN </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>


        <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={.7} style={styles.btnLogin} onPress={()=> this.openDatabaseIShipWithApp()}>
          <Text style={styles.textsubmit} > LOGIN </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>


   
      </ImageBackground>
  );}
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  backgroundContainer:{
    flex: 1,
    width: null,
    height: null,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  logoLogin:{
    width: 60,
    height: 80,
    borderRadius:10
  },
  logoContainer:{
    alignItems:'center',
    marginBottom: 50
  },
  logoText:{
    color: 'white',
    fontSize: 15,
    fontWeight: '500',
    marginTop: 10,
    opacity: 0.8
  },
  inputUsername:{
    width: WIDTH - 75,
    height: 45,
    borderRadius: 45,
    fontSize: 16,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    backgroundColor: '#e3e3e3',
    color: 'black',
    paddingLeft: 48,
    marginTop: 15,
    marginHorizontal: 25,
    opacity: 0.5
  },
  inputIcon:{
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 21,
    left: 43
  },
  btnEye:{
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 24,
    right: 43
  },
  btnLogin:{
    width: WIDTH - 75,
    height: 45,
    borderRadius: 45,
    backgroundColor: '#2bb358',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    marginTop: 30,
  },
  textsubmit: {
    color: 'white',
    fontSize: 18,
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontWeight: 'bold'
  },
  textLogin:{
    color: 'white',
    fontSize: 26,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    marginTop: 30,
  }
});

const mapStateToProps = (state) =>{
  return{
    dataUser: state.auth.dataUser,
    lpin: state.auth.pin,
    username:state.auth.username,
    loggedin: state.auth.loggedin
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(Login);

this is the metro config
const { getDefaultConfig } = require('@expo/metro-config');

const defaultConfig = getDefaultConfig(__dirname);

module.exports = {
  resolver: {
    assetExts: [...defaultConfig.resolver.assetExts, 'db'],
  },
};

this is the package.json
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/metro-config": "^0.1.43",
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.6.2",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "3.0.0",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "^1.9.3",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "expo": "~39.0.2",
    "expo-asset": "~8.2.0",
    "expo-file-system": "~9.2.0",
    "expo-image-picker": "~9.1.1",
    "expo-sharing": "~8.4.1",
    "expo-sqlite": "~8.4.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.0.2",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "native-base": "^2.13.8",
    "patch-package": "^6.2.2",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-csv": "^2.0.3",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-39.0.4.tar.gz",
    "react-native-awesome-alerts": "^1.4.2",
    "react-native-elements": "^1.2.7",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.5.0",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^9.1.0",
    "react-native-numeric-input": "^1.8.3",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.4.0",
    "react-native-screens": "^1.0.0-alpha.23",
    "react-native-searchable-list": "^1.1.3",
    "react-native-simple-toast": "^1.1.3",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-touchable-scale": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.13.12",
    "react-navigation": "^4.0.10",
    "react-navigation-drawer": "^2.3.3",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^1.10.3",
    "react-navigation-tabs": "^2.5.6",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.3",
    "redux": "^4.0.4",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-promise-middleware": "^6.1.2",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "~7.9.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code to open database

```
async function openDb() {
    if (!(await FileSystem.getInfoAsync(FileSystem.documentDirectory + 
'SQLite')).exists) {
        await FileSystem.makeDirectoryAsync(FileSystem.documentDirectory + 
'SQLite');
    }
    await FileSystem.downloadAsync(
        Asset.fromModule(require('./assets/db/user.db')).uri,
        FileSystem.documentDirectory + 'SQLite/user.db'
    );
    return SQLite.openDatabase('user.db');
}
const db = openDb();
```

Then create file metro.config.js in the root directory of your application and add this code to it

```
const { getDefaultConfig } = require('expo/metro-config');

const defaultConfig = getDefaultConfig(__dirname);

module.exports = {
  resolver: {
    assetExts: [...defaultConfig.resolver.assetExts, 'db'],
  },
};
```

That code in metro.config.js allows your application to recognize any .db file extensions

Then lastly, stop and restart your application, Cheers